# How do I replace quotation marks, brackets and numbers from array?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
mylist = [('Bill', 1), ('John', 1), ('Tony', 2), ('Phill', 2)]
```

I want to remove the quotation marks and the numbers so only names would remain.

I want something like this:

```
[Bill, John, Tony,  Phill]
```

Comment: Are you trying to output the array as a string? Please specify what you mean by 'removing' the quotation marks 'from the array'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [('Bill', 1), ('John', 1), ('Tony', 2), ('Phill', 2)]
print([x for x, y in mylist])
```

Output:

```
['Bill', 'John', 'Tony', 'Phill']
```

Or if you also want without quotes, try:

```
print('[' + ', '.join([x for x, y in mylist]) + ']')
```

Or `zip(*...)`:

```
print('[' + ', '.join(list(zip(*mylist))[0]) + ']')
```

Both output:

```
[Bill, John, Tony, Phill]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I'm checking

Comment: @MZ Ooh thanks for the catch, I fixed it. But how should I fix the `zip` solution?

Comment: @MZ that is not accurate. Check this answer. Specifically with `join`, using a list-comp is actually better... https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/6045800

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ooh yeah forget about that post, remember reading it. I think that's why i did it with the brackets

Comment: Thanks Guys. It worked. It's the best pyhton community in the world)))

Comment: It says after 2mins